# Spring Integration redelivery via errorChannel throw with JmsTransactionManager doesnt honor maximumRedeliveries

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Related to SO question: [Spring Integration Java DSL using JMS retry/redlivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826497/spring-integration-java-dsl-using-jms-retry-redlivery/51827640)

Using a transacted poller and JmsTransactionManager on a connectionFactory with maximumRedeliveries set to 3 results in a doubling of the actual redlievery attempts.

How can I get this to honor the redelivery settings of the connection factory?

My connectionFactory is built as:

```
 @Bean (name="spring-int-connection-factory")
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory(){
        return buildConnectionFactory(
                brokerUrl,
                DELAY_2_SECS,
                MAX_REDELIVERIES,
                "spring-int");
    }

 public static ActiveMQConnectionFactory buildConnectionFactory(String brokerUrl, Long retryDelay, Integer maxRedeliveries, String clientIdPrefix){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqcf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        amqcf.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        amqcf.setClientIDPrefix(clientIdPrefix);
        if (maxRedeliveries != null) {
            if (retryDelay == null) {
                retryDelay = 500L;
            }
            RedeliveryPolicy rp = new org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy();
            rp.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(retryDelay);
            rp.setRedeliveryDelay(retryDelay);
            rp.setMaximumRedeliveries(maxRedeliveries);
        }
        return amqcf;
    }
```

My flow with poller is as:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow2(@Qualifier("spring-int-connection-factory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        IntegrationFlow flow =  IntegrationFlows.from(
                Jms.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .configureJmsTemplate(t -> t.receiveTimeout(1000).sessionTransacted(true))
                        .destination(INPUT_DIRECT_QUEUE),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers
                        .fixedDelay(5000)
                        .transactional()
                        .errorChannel("customErrorChannel")
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(2))
        ).handle(this.msgHandler).get();

        return flow;
    }
```

My errorChannel handler simply re-throws which causes JMS redelivery to happen.

When I run this with the handler set to always throw an exception, I see that the message handler actually receives the message 7 times (1 initial and 6 redeliveries).

I expected only 3 redeliveries according to my connectionFactory config.

Any ideas what is causing the doubling of attempts and how to mitigate it?

Comment: Please show all of your configuration; according to the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html) 6 is the default `maximumRedeliveries`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me - stops at 4...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51792909Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So51792909Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51792909Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                template.convertAndSend("foo", "test");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .destination("foo"), e -> e
                            .poller(Pollers
                                    .fixedDelay(5000)
                                    .transactional()
                                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(2)))
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    System.out.println(h.get("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    throw new RuntimeException("foo");
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        return new JmsTransactionManager(cf);
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqCF() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
        RedeliveryPolicy rp = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        rp.setMaximumRedeliveries(3);
        cf.setRedeliveryPolicy(rp);
        return cf;
    }

    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(amqCF());
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "ActiveMQ.DLQ")
    public void listen(String in) {
        logger.info(in);
    }

}
```

Comment: Argh! and Thanks! Even my code in orig shows that I was creating a RedeliveryPolicy but NOT setting it on the ConnectionFactory. Doh!  Glad you noticed my test case similarity to AMQ default of 6.