# Error handling in PublishSubscribeChannel

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I'm using Spring Integration using DSL for handling communication between JMS and REST service. The requirement is that messages should be redelivered indefinetly. In one case, I have to sequentially execute two operations. If first one fails, the second one shouldn't be executed, but in case it's 4xx error I shouldn't try to redeliver it. My code looks like this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(Jms.container(connectionFactory, destinationn)).get())
   .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
      .subscribe(firstRestOperation ->                                                  
         firstRestOperation
         .transform(originalMessageToFirstRequestTransformer())
         .handle(Http.outboundGateway(restApiBaseUri + "/first-endpoint", restTemplate)
                     .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).get())  //when this handler receives HTTP Status 4xx, 
                                                          //second operation shouldn't be executed and 
                                                          //and message shouldn't be redelievered
      .subscribe(secondRestOperation->
         secondRestOperation
         .transform(originalMessageToSecondRequestTransformer())
         .handle(Http.outboundGateway(restApiBaseUri + "/second-endpoint", restTemplate).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).get())
).get();

class MyErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler { //this is used in Option B


    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if(response.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError()){
            log.warn(...);
        }else{
            super.handleError(response);
        }
    }
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   restTemplate.setErrorHandler(myErrorHandler); //this is used in Option B
   return restTemplate;
}
```

How can I meet these requirements? Only idea I have is to somehow interrupt IntegrationFlow while commiting JMS session.

Thanks for any suggestions.

*UPDATE*

Option A: Currently:

- operation 1 fails with any error
- operation 2 is not executed
- message is redelivered indefinetly

Option B: I can also handle 4xx error, then:

- operation 1 fails with 4xx, exception is handled
- operation 2 is executed
- integration flow finishes ok, JMS Session is commited and message is not being redelivered

but this causes operation 2 to be executed

What I need is:

- operation 1 fails with 4xx
- operation 2 is *not* executed
- message is *not* redelivered

*UPDATE 2*

I think I might be getting somewhere. As @gary-russel suggested I added error channel, and handled 4xx errors:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageProducerSupport inputUpsertCustomerMessageProducerSupport() {
        return Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(Jms.container(connectionFactory, destination).messageSelector(jmsSelector)).errorChannel(errorHandlingChannel).get();
    }


    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel errorHandlingChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter() {
        ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter router = new ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter();
        router.setChannelMapping(HttpClientErrorException.class.getName(), "clientErrorMessageChannel");
        router.setDefaultOutputChannel(unhandledErrorsChannel());
        return router;
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(customErrorChannel())
                .log()
                .route(errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter())
                .get();
    }
    

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel clientErrorMessageChannel(){
        return MessageChannels
                .direct()
                .get();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow clientErrorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(clientErrorMessageChannel())
                .handle(message -> log.warn(...)    //handle error here
                .get();
    }


        @Bean
    public MessageChannel unhandledErrorsChannel(){
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }
    
        @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow unhandledErrorsFlow(){
        //how should I implement it?
    }
```

I want to handle ONLY 4xx error, the rest should be propagated and should cause JMS message redelivery. I tried not setting `defaultOutputChannel` in `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter` (than another exception is thrown) or setting `defaultOutputChannel` to default `errorChannel` (than all of the errors are handled).

*UPDATE 3*

Found solution in: [Spring Integration Java DSL using JMS retry/redlivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826497/spring-integration-java-dsl-using-jms-retry-redlivery)

Here's code for my error handling flow:

```
 @Bean
    public MessageProducerSupport inputUpsertCustomerMessageProducerSupport() {
        return Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(Jms.container(connectionFactory, destination).messageSelector(jmsSelector)).errorChannel(customErrorChannel()).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel customErrorChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter() {
        ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter router = new ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter();
        router.setChannelMapping(HttpClientErrorException.class.getName(), "clientErrorMessageChannel");
        router.setDefaultOutputChannel(unhandledErrorsChannel());
        return router;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel clientErrorMessageChannel(){
        return MessageChannels
                .direct()
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel unhandledErrorsChannel(){
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow unhandledErrorsFlow(){
        return IntegrationFlows.from(unhandledErrorsChannel()).handle("thisBeanName", "handleError").get();
    }

    public void handleError(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        log.warn("Received unhandled exception");
        throw t;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow clientErrorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(clientErrorMessageChannel())
                .handle(message -> log.warn("Received HTTP Status 4xx with message: " + ((MessageHandlingException)message.getPayload()).getCause().getMessage()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(customErrorChannel())
                .log()
                .route(errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter())
                .get();
    }
```

So the solution was to redirect exceptions to a flow that will handle them by rethrowing them. Too bad `BaseIntegrationFlow` doesn't have a method that accepts and throws `Throwable` - right now it's only possible by specifying bean and method name to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior; the second subscriber won't be called unless the `ignoreFailures` property is `true` (it is `false` by default).

You need to show the upstream flow, but to "catch" the exception you need to add an error channel to the (presumably) message-driven inbound adapter and handle the exception there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the question to better show what I tried and what are my requirements - as you can see in second case, I tried to handle the error, but then second operation is not interrupted.

Comment: As I said - you need to show more code. And explain what `exception is handled` means - if you handle the exception in the service then, yes, of course the next operation will proceed; the service must throw an exception to stop the broadcast.

Comment: I've updated my question to cover basically all of my IntegrationFlow code minus logging, filters etc. I've also added transformers to make it clear why I've used `PublishSubscribeChannel`