# Spring Integration Java DSL SFTP Exception Handling

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am using spring Integration for my file transfer

following code is working fine, but if I remove folder from source directory It start throwing exceptions.

```
IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
            .localDirectory(new File(classLoader.getResource(".").getFile() + "/files/" + String.valueOf(config.getId())))
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundDirectory()), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(4_000)))
            .transform((File f) -> pgpEncryption.encrypt(f))
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectory(config.getOutboundDirectory()), c -> c.advice(sftpConfig.deleteFileAdvice())
            )
            .get();
```

follwing is the exception if source folder doest not exists.

```
2018-10-01 17:13:02.362 ERROR 12320 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 2: No such file
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:331)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:260)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:43)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:262)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:391)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:385)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 2: No such file
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:286)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 2: No such file
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:103)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.list(CachingSessionFactory.java:218)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.lambda$synchronizeToLocalDirectory$1(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:287)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:436)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: 2: No such file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2225)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2242)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1592)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:91)
    ... 25 more
```

so, what will be the way to catch this exception and log appropriate message.
I will have some other problems too like invalid server ip, invalid private key.

Comment: you should check the directory exists or not before uploading file. If directory not exists should create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException:` really comes from the global `errorChannel` configured to the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` by default. You can provide your own variant via `SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec` and its `poller()`configuration:

```
e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(4_000).errorChannel(myErrorChannel))
```

This custom channel can be subscribed as any other one and there you can handle an `ErrorChannel` whatever way you need. The `@ServiceActivator` or other `IntegrationFlow` can be used on the matter.

Comment: can you please provide me an example? I have more then 10 IntegrationFlows running, how to check this exception is from which integration.

`@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public Message<?> errorChannelHandler(ErrorMessage errorMessage){}`

I am able to access message pay load in this and returning `MessageBuilder`

but it still log in console plus I need to get id of this integrationFlow.

Comment: As I said: you can use custom channels for error. No need to rely on the global `errorChannel`. This way each flow will have its own error handling. And there won't be need to introduce some severing logic. You can't get a flow id in the message: there are not related. The first one is just a logical container for better readability of source code. The second one is active data transfer object. Well, it even actually may don't know about any channels and handlers it passes.

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions during the execution of a message are sent to the 'errorChannel' by default. 
You could define a service activator on this channel and provide your exception handling logic.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
public MyExceptionHandler exceptionHandler() {
  return new MyExceptionHandler ();
}
```

See - 
[Spring Integration DSL ErrorHandling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899044/spring-integration-dsl-errorhandling) 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler